# Passport authentication strageties with Grunt

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, passport.js

Question concerns setting up the development environment (later on other environment like production)....

Using latest of Node, Passport, and Grunt but Express still in the 3 chain.

Working on an application leveraging external authentication only (i.e. no local Passport strategy).  The oauth client id, secret key and callback configuration per strategy (i.e. Google, Facebook etc.) is nothing (obviously) to be housed in Git.

Wondering how people tackle this with different environments?  Just getting my feet wet with Grunt so I am currently registering a task (after the initConfig which reads my package.json) that reads a authentication configuration (excepting an authentication property in package.json):

```
grunt.registerTask('auth', function() {
    var pkg = grunt.config('pkg');
    var util = require('util');

    if (grunt.file.exists(pkg.authentication)) {
      grunt.log.writeln(util.format('Setting up authentication with %s', pkg.authentication));

      var auth = grunt.file.readJSON(pkg.authentication);
      .... // move auth data into a auth.js read by the application
    } else 
      grunt.fail.warn(util.format('%s not found (authentication property in package.json), neccessary for authentication but not managaged by Git', pkg.authentication));        
  });
```

Basically, the developer/installer is responsible for having a private (not managed by Git), local settings for authentication.  Something like:

```
{
  'googleAuth' : {
    'clientID'  : 'your-secret-clientID-here',
    'clientSecret'  : 'your-client-secret-here',
    'callbackURL'   : 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback'
  }
}
```

A simple copy of the JSON contents into a auth.js file put in the build directory required by the application will work.

Better way?

Comment: Why are you doing this in grunt and not in the node app itself?

Comment: @Matt, the client id and secret stuff is nothing for pushing publicly into Git (i.e. like the actual Node app itself).  Provide a "template" in the code managed by Git that a developer/installer has to copy and edit then this is recopied by Grunt (now with a standard Grunt copy rather than my custom task).  More of a configuration management question.

Comment: Are you using .gitignore to omit config files from the repo?